# Stereo Calibration Worked Scaled Images?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Does stereo calibration still work if the right image is scaled a bit different than the left, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for two reasons:

1. The triangulation of the 3D point will be affected
2. Your correspondences will be inaccurate if you are using scale-variant interest point.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why my rectified images were outrageously distorted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, stereo calibration can still work if you have two different images. You have to make sure the calibration takes the difference into account (so the default OpenCV version won't work) and for best results you should try to make sure the cameras are synchronized.

- It will be less accurate (more correspondence errors as [Jacob notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959718/stereo-calibration-worked-scaled-images/6960270#6960270)
- The Field of View of the stereo pair will be restricted to the smaller of the images, and than just to the overlapping area between the two images.
- You will probably have to write your own calibration  and rectification code. I'm not aware of any libraries that can do it.